# iOS App crash at method call

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, memory-management, crash

I have an app in iOS that crashes as soon as I call a particular method (anywhere in the program) but before that method starts to execute. I put an `NSLog` at the very top of the method and it outputs a message that doesn't get sent before the app crashes.

The app crashes as soon as this method is referenced anywhere in the program. The method name is `-(void) LaunchReel;`  and I have included it (obviously) in my header file as well. The program crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error and references an integer data type.

It crashes in the **0 objc_msgSend thread**, and this error also occurs in the **2 __CFStringAppendFormatCore** thread. I have no idea why this is occurring. Could it be a possible hung debugger process?

Comment: that really is not much info to work with..

Comment: Post full error output and part of the code where you create an object and send message to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this has happened to me, it's because my code expects one type of object and is getting another. For example, you are passing a parameter into a function that is of type NSNumber, but the function expects NSString, so when it tries to format a string with CFStringAppendFormatCore, the app crashes.

Make sure the object is the type you expect when running into an error like this.

Comment: One way to debug wrong-type problems is to turn on NSZombies.